# How do I use CanvasJS elements in React without using JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvasjs

Why not JSX? It simply doesn't work. I recently asked a question about it and was suggested to drop the `type="text/jsx"` attribute, therefore leaving me with only JS syntax to work with.

In that sense, I understood that it's totally possible to go without JSX, for instance

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({liked: true})}>
  Like
</button>
```

can be simply rewritten as

```
React.createElement(
  "button",
  {onClick: () => this.setState({liked: true})},
  "Like"
)
```

so far so good. But how would I rewrite something like this?

```
<div>
  <CanvasJS.Chart options = {options} 
    onRef={ref => this.chart = ref}
  />
  <span id="timeToRender" style={spanStyle}></span>
</div>
```

Here, `CanvasJS.Chart` is not a native HTML tag, but a class in the CanvasJS library. I tried creating an instance like

```
let canvasJSChart = new CanvasJS.Chart(
  ???,
  {options, onRef: ref => this.chart = ref}
);
```

but I don't know what to put in place of `???`, which should be the DOM id of the chart's container, which is the external *div* in the last JSX example. I cannot have access to that element yet, because I need to pass `canvasJSChart` as argument "children" in the *div*'s constructor.

I also tried using another *div* to temporarily contain `canvasJSChart` before I could pass it to its actual container (alongside the `timeToRender` *span*), like this:

```
let timeToRender = React.createElement(
  "span",
  {id: "timeToRender", style}
);

let canvasJsChart = new CanvasJS.Chart(
  "temp",
  {options, onRef: ref => this.chart = ref}
)

React.createElement(
  "div",
  {},
  // children:
  timeToRender,
  canvasJSChart
);
```

While `timeToRender` gives me no problems at all and renders perfectly, as soon as I add `canvasJSChart` to the children, I get an `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child`, which is really odd, because `timeToRender` is indeed an Object but it still works perfectly.

What am I missing? How can I let a CanvasJS element be a child of a React element?

Comment: You do it exactly the same way, the only difference between `<foo />` and `<Bar />` is that the former becomes a string and the latter doesn't, `createElement("foo", ...)` vs. `createElement(Bar, ...)`. You don't need to `new` up `CanvasJS.Chart`, React will do that for you.

Comment: It was that simple eh? Thank you so much, you have no idea how relieved I am, after so many headaches. Thanks again!